# Image Segmentation in MATLAB using adaptive threshold function

Tags: matlab, function, image-processing, image-segmentation, image-thresholding

I have written some lines of code using the following function:

```
adaptivethreshold(IM,ws,c)
```

and it gives me a Mask `bw`. I multiply this mask with my original image `bb` and show the result.

```
clear
clc
bb=dicomread('30421573');
figure(1)
imagesc(bb)
bw=adaptivethreshold(bb,50,128);
imaa=double(bw).*double(bb);
figure(2)
image(imaa)
```

the original Image and the result are shown:
[image]
[image]

It does not seem to be giving me any mask for my image. Is there any way I can extract those yellow parts from my results?

Comment: Are you using [this File Exchange function](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8647-local-adaptive-thresholding)? That would be important to mention in your question. The Image Processing Toolbox has [`adaptthresh`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/adaptthresh.html), which is significantly different.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create the mask before applying to the image, i.e.

```
bw=adaptivethreshold(bb,50,128);
BW = imbinarize(bb,bw);
imaa=double(bw).*double(BW);
figure(2)
image(imaa)
```

Comment: This would be true if OP used `adaptthresh` from the Image Processing Toolbox. But it is not clear which function OP actually uses, see [my other comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58664133/image-segmentation-in-matlab-using-adaptive-threshold-function#comment103635065_58664133).